# font-size em unit inheritance issue

Tags: css

Actual `p` (string 'ABC') font-size is 24px and `li`('First' and 'Second') is 20px in the example below.

I was expecting 24px font-size of `li` elements also.
What is the issue here?

font-size is an inherited CSS property and `li` should ideally inherit computed font-size(24px) of parent `p` element in this case.

```css
div{
    font-size:20px;
}

p{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
       ABC
      <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't just randomly throw `li` around without a containing list.  Once you break standards you can't expect other things to follow them.

Comment: oops my mistake.thanks got it write it as answer

Comment: Even though you have the `<p>ABC<li>...</p>`, it is interpreted as `<p>ABC</p><li>..` .

Comment: @MattWhipple - It does not matter - Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wACL6/1/

Comment: It does matter...it means the DOM is still invalid if the browser is moving the list outside of the `p`.  You likely can't structure the code that way...looking for more info now.

Comment: Even after adding ul, font-size of ul and li is 20px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just randomly throw `li`s around without a containing list. Once you break standards you can't expect other things to follow them.

You also cannot put lists inside of `p`s. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

"List elements (in particular, ol and ul elements) cannot be children of p elements."

Comment: Though it is invalid HTML syntax, On fixing it, the problem still exists. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/wACL6/1/